# Add pbixrefresher to Python

Tags: python, powerbi

I've got trouble installing the pbixrefresher add-on on Python.
I tried downloading different versions of Python and still have an error :

[image]

Is anyone able to tell me what to do to get it working ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

first try "pip install cloudpickle" and then "pip install pbixrefresher".i'm using python 3.5(64-bit).its working fine for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhW7j.png)